# How to select all the column based minimum date value in a sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to extract the rows which have minimum date based on condition.

**My data set:**

[image]

**My desired output:**

[image]

**Steps I tried:**

1. I tried remove duplicate function but it did not worked.
2. I also tried MINIF function but it did not worked as well.

Please suggest?

Comment: Which version of Excel do you have @Alex? And is your data pre-sorted into name and date order (or to be more exact, are  repeat purchases for the same customer  kept together and in ascending order of date)?

Comment: @TomSharpe, My version is 2013 and repeat purchases for the same customer are kept together in ascending order of date

Answer (score 1):

With Office 365, you could do:

```
=INDEX(tbl, MATCH(UNIQUE(tbl[NAME])&MINIFS(tbl[SBL Transaction Date],tbl[NAME],UNIQUE(tbl[NAME])),tbl[NAME]&tbl[SBL Transaction Date],0), SEQUENCE( 1, COLUMNS(tbl) ) )
```

[image]

Here is a more readable version:

```
=INDEX( tbl,
        MATCH( UNIQUE(tbl[NAME])
                & MINIFS(tbl[SBL Transaction Date], tbl[NAME],UNIQUE(tbl[NAME])),
               tbl[NAME]&tbl[SBL Transaction Date],
               0),
        SEQUENCE( 1, COLUMNS(tbl) ) )
```

This requires SEQUENCE & UNIQUE, so that will require Excel 365. If you have and older version, then an entirely different approach would be needed.

Answer (score 1):

Another way

```
=FILTER(A2:D10,(COUNTIFS(A2:A10,A2:A10,D2:D10,"<"&D2:D10)=0)*(A2:A10<>""))
```

[image]

If you don't have Excel 365, you could just put the result from the countifs part of the formula in a separate column and filter on it as shown in column K.

```
=(COUNTIFS(A2:A10,A2:A10,D2:D10,"<"&D2:D10)=0)*(A2:A10<>"")
```

If the data is kept in order of date within each customer, you could also use a very simple filter with a helper column containing

```
=A2<>A1
```

Comment: Really clever stuff!

Comment: Thanks! But I'm not totally satisfied with it because it would show duplicates if there was a tie on minimum date.

Comment: What I like about it is the use of COUNTIFS to create a minimum. That is a useful method. But to be fair, the data seem to be unlikely to contain duplicates in any case. Your approach is super concise.