# Excel sort function to "skip" 1st row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spill-range

My question is because I wanted to sort the data as provided in the following question:
[How to select all the column based minimum date value in a sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68646564/how-to-select-all-the-column-based-minimum-date-value-in-a-sheet)

What I wanted to do is select the data (`Range A1:F9`) and sort it:

| NAME | CARD NUMBER | ACCOUNT NUMBER | SBL Transaction Type | SBL Transaction Amount | SBL Transaction Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B | 4779 | 1 | POS purchase | 280 | 02-08-2021 |
| B | 4779 | 1 | POS purchase | 1 | 03-05-2021 |
| S | 1475 | 2 | POS purchase | 389 | 05-04-2021 |
| S | 1475 | 2 | POS purchase | 755 | 05-11-2021 |
| S | 1475 | 2 | POS purchase | 1794 | 05-15-2021 |
| A | 0173 | 3 | POS purchase | 1 | 02-01-2021 |
| A | 0173 | 3 | POS purchase | 1 | 02-02-2021 |
| A | 0173 | 3 | POS purchase | 1 | 02-03-2021 |

What I did is select the data including header `=SORT(A1:F9,6)` and which results in sorting the header along with the data (of course):

[image: SortinclHeader]

I then got the idea to have the SORT function to disregard the first row and then sort the rest.
My first attempt was `=IF(ROW(A1:F9)=1,A1:F9,SORT(A1:F9,6))`

[image: Attempt1]

As you can see the header worked fine, but the sorted data includes the header, since it's the last in range after sorting `A1:F9`.

Excluding the header row from the sort range `=IF(ROW(A1:F9)=1,A1:F9,SORT(A2:F9,6))` also doesn't work, since the range is then smaller than the output range resulting in the following error and still skips one data line:

[image: Attempt2]

I managed to get it correct by inserting a substitute header of al zeroes to the sort range and than sort stack the sorted range onto the headers with this function (which also gives room for two row headers):

`=LET(D,A1:F9,rowD,ROW(D),rowsD,ROWS(D),colsD,COLUMNS(D),H,A1:F1,header,INDEX(D,1,1):INDEX(D,ROWS(H),COLUMNS(H)),subsHeader,SEQUENCE(1,colsD,0,0),subsD,IF(rowD<=ROWS(header),subsHeader,D),sortedSubsD,SORT(subsD,6),IF(SEQUENCE(rowsD)<=ROWS(header),header,sortedSubsD))`

But I wondered if there's a more elegant way using formula to sort a data range without affecting the header.

Result is `=LET(data;A1:F9;header;A1:F2;sortCol;6;SORTBY(data;IF(ROW(data)>ROWS(header);1;0);1;INDEX(data;;sortCol);1))` thanks to Darren Bartrup-Cook's contribution.

Comment: Why are you not just sorting it from the Home menu on the ribbon?

Comment: Doesn't `=SORT(A2:F9,6)` work?

Comment: Just start from `A2` instead of `A1`.

Comment: I know it works like that and I can easily use the sort built in Excel, but I like to be able to write it as formula, so we can spill it at one go, instead of having to spill the headers separately from the data (as the headers are part of the data). So sorting A2:F9 would give the sorted range without the headers.

Comment: Just copy the headers across.

Comment: The question is to not do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a spare column add a 0 next to the header and leave the other rows blank.  You can then sort on that column first, followed by the other column.

[image]

You can then SORTBY column A and then column F.
`=SORTBY(B1:F6,A1:A6,1,F1:F6,1)`

[image]

Comment: nice! I managed to calculate that using `=SORTBY(A1:F9;IF(ROW(A1:F9)>ROWS(A1:F2);1;0);1;F1:F9;1)`
where A1:F9 = the data and A1:F2 would be headers. No helper needed then. (or `=LET(data;A1:F9;header;A1:F2;SORTBY(data;IF(ROW(data)>ROWS(header);1;0);1;F1:F9;1))`)

Comment: Nice improvement. :)

Comment: thanks. Final version: `=LET(data;A1:F9;header;A1:F2;sortCol;6;SORTBY(data;IF(ROW(data)>ROWS(header);1;0);1;INDEX(data;;sortCol);1))`